# How do I load balance Lucene.Net?

Tags: lucene.net, load-balancing

Is it possible to load balance a Lucene.NET index across multiple processes / servers?

Since Lucene.NET is filebased is it possible to just make a simple filecopy (using i.e. robocopy) of the index to the servers serving queries?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, no problems to be expected here if you are really only reading / searching the index.