# Does Amazon has APIs to index and search through documents stored using Amazon S3?

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, full-text-search, amazon-s3

I have a lots of documents stored on Amazon S3. My questions are:

Does Amazon provide any services/APIs using which I can index the contents of the document and search them (full text indexing and searching)?

If it does could someone please point me to any link in the documentation.

If it does not then could this be achieved with Lucene and Zend Framework? Have any one of you implemented this? Can I get some pointers?

**UPDATE:** I do not intend to save my index on Amazon S3 rather I am looking forward to indexing the contents of the documents on S3 and serving them based on a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738634/best-way-to-keyword-search-amazon-simpledb-using-ec2-and-asp-net), or [this blog post](http://www.kimchy.org/lucene-and-amazon-s3/) if you want to do pure lucene, or you can use [Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrOnAmazonEC2), which is probably easier. See also [this post](http://www.intellog.com/blog/?p=198).

Zend has a PHP port of Lucene, which ties in very well. You can look at the Zend documentation for how to use it.